# In python how do I pass a scalar argument to an OpenCL kernel?

Tags: python, opencl, pyopencl

I am using the python bindings for OpenCL and I have written a kernel that expects a scalar (float) argument, but I can not figure out the proper way to pass it in.

If I simply invoke

```
prg.bloop(queue, [width,height], None, centers_g, 16/9, result_g)
```

I get this error:

```
pyopencl.cffi_cl.LogicError: when processing argument #2 (1-based): 'float' does not support the buffer interface
```

If I wrap it with `numpy.float32(16/9)` then the kernel behaves as if it were passed 0 instead of 1.7777777 .

Here is more of the source code in case that helps you understand what I'm doing.

```
def mission2(cells, width, height):
    ctx = cl.create_some_context()
    queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)

    centers = numpy.array(list(cells), dtype=numpy.float32)

    centers_g = cl.Buffer(ctx, cl.mem_flags.READ_ONLY|cl.mem_flags.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf = centers)

    prg = cl.Program(ctx, """
__kernel void test1(__global char *out) {
    out[0] = 77;
}

float sphere(float r, float x, float y)
{
    float q = r*r-(x*x+y*y);
    if (q<0)
        return 0;
    return sqrt(q);
}

__kernel void bloop(__global const float centers[][6], float aspect, __global char * out)
{
    int u = get_global_id(0);
    int v = get_global_id(1);
    int width = get_global_size(0);
    int height = get_global_size(1);

    float x = u/(float)width * aspect;
    float y = v/(float)height;

    float max = sphere(0.3, x-centers[0][0], y-centers[0][1]);

    int idx = u+v*width;
    out[idx] = 255*max;

}

    """).build()

    result_g = cl.Buffer(ctx, cl.mem_flags.WRITE_ONLY, width*height)


    if False:
        prg.test1(queue, [width,height], None, result_g)
    else:
        prg.bloop(queue, [width,height], None, centers_g, numpy.float32(16/9), result_g)


    result = numpy.zeros([height,width], dtype=numpy.uint8)
    future = cl.enqueue_copy(queue, result, result_g)
    future.wait()

    print(result)

    imsave("/tmp/bloop.png", result, cmap = matplotlib.pyplot.get_cmap('gray'))
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not behaving as if it was passed 1?  16/9 gives 1 in Python 2.  Wrapping in numpy.float32 is what I do when using PyOpenCL and it works here.

Comment: centers is not defined in your kernel. It's defined in your host code. The error says it: Buffer interface is not defined for floats. 'centers' is a float. So centers[][6] is illegal.

Comment: I am not using python 2.  This is a python 3 app and when I `print(16/9)` it definitely gives me 1.77777.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to pass scalars to an OpenCL kernel you can use the set_scalar_arg_dtypes function like this:

```
kernel = prg.bloop
kernel.set_scalar_arg_dtypes( [None, numpy.float32, None] )
kernel(queue, [width, height], None, centers_g, aspect, result_g)
```

[The manual page](https://documen.tician.de/pyopencl/runtime.html#pyopencl.Kernel.set_scalar_arg_dtypes) clearly states that it will not work if you code it like this:

```
prg.bloop.set_scalar_arg_dtypes( [None, numpy.float32, None] )
# this will fail:
prg.bloop(queue, [width, height], None, centers_g, 16/9, result_g)
```

because "The information set by this rountine is attached to a single kernel instance. A new kernel instance is created every time you use program.kernel attribute access."